# Configuring DNS on multiple domain name with separated Nameservers

Tags: azure, godaddy

I have a virtual machine on Azure that is hosting a company product website.

We have a domain name (www.example123.com) at Godaddy.com with SSL certification bound to our virtual machine.

We are using Cynet Cpanel for email services, using mail.example123.com.

## Problem

> Godaddy: www.example123.com
>
> Cynet: example123.com

1) When people search www.example123.com (godaddy) it is clashing with example123.com (cynet host)

2) How to make both domain names work?

```
 i. Godaddy domain will point to Virtual Machine IIS webhost
ii. Godaddy will point only MX Record to Cynet mail.example123.com
```

3) How to avoid these DNS clashing into each other?

4) Can we permanently redirect example123.com (Cynet) to www.example123.com (Godaddy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what are you using as your nameservers for the domain, I would recommend using GoDaddy's DNS service which is included with your domain registration.

- Go to GoDaddy and login, click on your account and go to "My Domains", click on the Gear for the domain and then "Manage DNS"
- Make sure the nameservers are set to the GoDaddy's ones, if not click on Change and set it to Default. (this change may take 24 to 48 hours to replicate all over the internet).
- Configure all the DNS records:

  - Create an A record for example123.com and point it to the IP of the Azure VM
  - Create another A record www.example123.com also pointing to Azure VM
  - Create A record for mail.example123.com and point to the IP of the Cynet email server
  - Create MX record pointing to mail.example123.com

That should do it, here is the GoDaddy help on managing your DNS: [link](https://ca.godaddy.com/help/manage-dns-680)